# Introduction to nests

Tags: soft-question

I've just read Chapter 7 of Alice in Numberland by Baylis and Haggarty, it's called "Nests - in which the rationals give birth to the reals and the scene is set for arithmetic in $\mathbb{R}$". Unfortunately, I could follow barely any of this chapter - I've tried to find an introduction to nests online but I can't really find anything. Does anyone know a good resource for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is it perhaps a play on words, "nests" as a pun on "nets" and [the approach to convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics))?

Comment: Ahh, thank you. No wonder I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a fun book, but I'm unfamiliar with it.  Any sincere imitation of Lewis Carroll (Rev. Charles L. Dodson) would entail some word play.

Here I suspect "nests" is used as proxy for [nets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_%28mathematics%29), a way of approaching convergence that's more general than limits of sequences.

Sequences are good enough for convergence in metric topological spaces, but one topic where we are spoonfed a little of the more general approach is when we tackle integration.  Refinement of partitions for Riemann integrals is an example of using nets to approximate, rather than sequences.